# Using an alphaMap is not providing transparency in my material

Tags: javascript, three.js, alpha, alphablending

I am trying to create chainlink surface.  I have 2 textures; a standard map which has the metallic look of the metal links with a white background (diffuse):

[image]

I also have an alpha map:

[image]

I am trying to apply both of these to a `MeshBasicMaterial` without luck:

```
var chainlinkMask = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/chainlink_Large-Panels_mask.png');
chainlinkMask.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
chainlinkMask.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
chainlinkMask.repeat.set( 2, 2 );

var chainlinkDiffuse = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture('textures/chainlink_Large-Panels_Diffuse.png');
chainlinkDiffuse.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
chainlinkDiffuse.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
chainlinkDiffuse.repeat.set( 2, 2 );

material.map = chainlinkMask;
material.alphaMap = chainlinkDiffuse;
material.transparency = true;
material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
```

This gives me the following:

[image]

As you can see, the alpha map isn't being applied.

Why not?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try setting the `transparent` parameter to `true` instead of `transparency`

```
material.transparent = true;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using an alpha map, use one of these two patterns when defining your material:

```
alphaMap: texture,
transparent: true,
```

or

```
alphaMap: texture,
alphaTest: 0.5, // if transparent is false
transparent: false,
```

Use the latter if possible, and avoid artifacts that can occur when transparent is true.

three.js r.85

Answer (score 0):

directly use `material.transparent` will cause rendering problem, for example. you have 2 corssing plane with each one applied `material.transparent = true`, and `material.side = DoubleSide`.  rotate it you will see rendering problem.
just use the solution @WestLangley mentioned above.